# Setting cookie expiration in Flask browser app

Tags: flask, cookies

I'm working on a web app in Flask and I'm trying to set a cookie that expires in 3 days.  Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/start')
def setcookie():
    expire_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    resp = make_response(render_template('start.html'))
    resp.set_cookie('mycookie',id_generator(6),max_age=expire_date,expires=expire_date)
    return resp
```

Despite this, when I inspect cookies in Chrome I see Expires/Max-age = Session

id_generator is a custom function generating a 6-har alphanumeric tracking id. I'm setting both max_age and expires because, well, neither worked so I'm trying both :-)

How do I set a custom expiration date or max-age for a cookie in a browser app?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the datetime expire_date you prepared is not compatible with the `max_age` parameter. Snippet from the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie):

> max_age (timedelta | int | None) – should be a number of seconds, or None (default) if the cookie should last only as long as the client’s browser session.

> expires (str | datetime | int | float | None) – should be a datetime object or UNIX timestamp.

if you use one of the two options below, you will get the desired result:

A. setting `expires` to datetime obj:

```
def setcookie():
    expire_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    resp = make_response(render_template('home.html'))
    resp.set_cookie('mycookie','somevaluehere',expires=expire_date)
    return resp
```

B. setting `max_age` to an integer:

```
def setcookie():
    resp = make_response(render_template('home.html'))
    resp.set_cookie('mycookie','somevaluehere',max_age=1234567)
    return resp
```